# How to include a file in LaTeX wihout causing a newpage

Tags: latex, include, page-break, pygments

I hope, this question is not too offtopic.

I have a bigger school project which involves some documentation. The documentation is a LaTeX file, and looks like this:

```
...
some explanation

\section {someCode}
\include{someCode.hs}
some explanation
...
```

The files `someCode.hs.tex` are auto-genereated from their corresponding `.hs`-Files using Pygments and a Makefile.

The Problem is: Each time, I include something, a pagebreak is inserted before. This is neither expected nor wanted. I googled, but found no answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: Problem: I've read that if you use \input then tex will not handle references and labels correctly between different files.  Is there a way to get references and labels to work right without the newpage?